# In what way are Fokker-Planck equations and Feynman path integrals equivalent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

1. [Feynman path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is equivalent to [Fokker–Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation). This is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation#Equivalent_techniques), but it's not clear why.
2. This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation#Fokker.E2.80.93Planck_equation_and_path_integral) says [Schrodinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) is also equivalent to [Fokker–Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) which makes me even more confused.

**Basically what I am asking is:**

How to show that Fokker-Plank:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x, t) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\mu(x, t) p(x, t)\right] + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[D(x, t) p(x, t)\right]$ is equivalent to path integral: $\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{Z}\int_{\mathbf{x}(0)=x} e^{iS(\mathbf{x},\dot{\mathbf{x}})}\psi_0(\mathbf{x}(t))\, \mathcal{D}\mathbf{x}$?

Where $S(\mathbf{x},\dot{\mathbf{x}})= \int L( \mathbf{x}(t),\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t))dt$ is the action (integral over the Lagrangian) and $\mathcal{D}\mathbf{x}$ stands for the integration over all possible paths?

Comment: Details of this are worked out in "Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena" by J. Zinn-Justin.

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310623/2451

Comment: http://www.theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~ajm/stoch09.pdf

Comment: @BobaFret Could you say where in the book it's addressed?

Comment: @J.G. I’ll check when I’m in my office again

Comment: Does this mean that "FP equation is in relation with path integral" as "Schroedinger equation is in relation with the path integral of Quantum Mechanics?". Namely: "the Sch equation is the FP equation in QM".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will start by apologising for a physicist's level of rigor in the following derivations but I think they give good insight into the connection between what I would call stochastic physics' Trinity of Langevin, Fokker-Planck and Path integral.

## Fokker-Planck from Langevin equation

Given a Langevin equation $dZ_t=b(Z_t)dt+\sigma(Z_t)dW_t$ (the most common form found in physics) we can derive the Fokker-Planck equation from the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation in a quick and dirty way:

$$
p(y,t|x)=\int dz\, p(y,t|z)p(z,t'|x)
$$

We suppose that $t = \delta t$ and thus we can write $$p(y,t|z) = \left\langle \delta (y-z-h)\right\rangle_h$$ where $h=\delta Z$ is defined by the associated Langevin equation. Now we have

$$
p(y,t|x)=\int dz\, \left\langle \delta (y-z-h)\right\rangle_hp(z,t'|x)\,.\tag{$\ast$}
$$

We can then Taylor expand the delta function as

$$
\left(1+\left\langle h\right\rangle \frac{\partial}{\partial y} +\frac{1}{2}\left\langle h^{2}\right\rangle \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} +\ldots\right)\delta(y-z) = (1+\mathscr{L})\delta(y-z)\,,
$$

then integrating by parts and the delta function we are left with

$$
p(y,t|x)=(1+\mathscr{L^\dagger})p(y,t'|x)\,.
$$

Expanding $p(y,t|x)= p(y,t'|x) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(y,t'|x) + \ldots$ in the limit $t \rightarrow 0$ we arrive at the Fokker-Planck equation

$$
\frac{\partial p(y,t|x)}{\partial t}=\mathscr{L^\dagger}p(y,t|x)
$$

relabelling $t'$ as $t$.

## Path integral from Langevin

We apply the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation many times:

$$
p(y,t|x)=\int\prod_{i=1}^{N}dz_{i}\, p(y,t_{N}|z_{N})\ldots p(z_{2},t_{2}|z_1)p(z_{1},t_{1}|x)
$$

And then use $(\ast)$ to replace each  along with the identity $\delta(x) = \int dk \exp(ikx)$ we get a sequence of averages over complex exponentials:

$$
p(y,t|x)=\int Dz Dk\, \left\langle e^{ik_N(z_N-z_{N-1}-h_N)}\right\rangle\ldots \left\langle e^{ik_2(z_2-z_{1}-h_2)}\right\rangle \left\langle e^{ik_1(z_1-x-h_1)}\right\rangle
$$

however we can still do better. Knowing the probability distribution of $h$ (usually Gaussian in physics) we can write 
$$
\left\langle O \right\rangle = \int dh P(h) O
$$
thus after replacing every averaged over exponential we get

$$
p(y,t|x)=\int Dz Dk Dh\, e^{i\int dt \,k\dot{z}} P[h_t]
$$

and when you perform the integrations over the paths of $k$ and $h$ you will get your path integral.

## Path integral from Fokker-Planck

I am less sure about how to go about directly showing the equivalence without the presence of a Langevin equation. However if we create a Lagrangian by multiplying the F-P equation by an auxiliary field and then integrate over all paths of our probability density and our auxiliary field, I have a feeling this will work but I am not certain so I will leave my answer here.

The main point of this is to show that the path integral and the FP equation are essentially two different representations of the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. As far as I can tell they are basically interchangeable and I hope someone more knowledgeable than myself can come in and explain why you would use one over the other in certain situations.

I hope this has been useful!

Comment: Can you please define symbols and letters?

Comment: Almost all symbols and letters used are standard notation. I'm assuming you are familiar with the propagator (little $p$). Big $P$ is the probability distribution of the generic random variable $O$ and in the context of the question would be the probability distribution of each step $h_i$ which in the continuum limit becomes a functional of the path $h_t$

Comment: Shouldn't the integral in the chapman-kolomogrov function be over dt' as well? What about dW shouldn't it be $dW_t$?

Comment: No to the first question, because what the C-K equation says is that at some time the particle must be at some point in our space. That is to say, pick an intermediate $t'$ and the particle must be somewhere, thus we integrate over all space, not time. Yes tot he second, I will correct this.

Comment: on the RHS you have an expression with t'. On the LHS there is only t. Without integrating over t' the LHS has to have t'.